# which collection should be efficient for this prob

Tags: java

in my project i have to store some data in the format in the Key=value  and later i will just read this value so which collection  will be suite for me .
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

What you're referring to is a Map.

If you're going to always access via key / value, use HashMap.  If you intend on cycling through all values, HashMap is horridly inefficient and so you should use LinkedHashMap instead.

Comment: `TreeMap` if he wants it sorted.

Comment: @madhurtanwani if you only need the values, then use `map.values()`, not `map.entrySet()`

Answer (score 1):

There are few things that you need to consider before you make any decision about selecting any decision

1. Whether the items needs to be ordered
2. Whether the items needs to be sorted
3. whether collection needs to be synchronized or not and many more
   Here is the link where you can get more information about the process of selecting the collection.
   http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/collections/how_to_choose.shtml

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the [map interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).